# Managing multiple apps with one Google Analytics account?

Tags: iphone, google-analytics, analytics

I've just setup a Google Analytics for Mobile Apps account and I've implemented the SDK in my iPhone app with no trouble at all. However, I haven't figured out how to manage multiple apps with one account. It seems fairly easy to setup multiple subdomains when dealing with websites and I've noticed the javascript code has a setSubdomain function that doesn't seem to be present in the iPhone SDK.

Is there any way I can have google analytics differentiate my different apps for the same account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up more profiles in GA - one profile per app. You should end up with UA codes like UA-XXXXX-1 and UA-XXXXX-2 - the XXXXX is the account identifier, and the suffix is the 'web property identifier' - in this case each app will have it's own property identifier. They don't match up 1-to-1 to GA profiles, as you can have more than one profile for a web-property-identifier (so you can have profiles with different filters on the same data), but in your case I'd suggest a separate web property IDs for each application.

Answer (score 0):

So the docs say:

> To use the SDK, you must create a free
>   account at www.google.com/analytics,
>   and create a new website profile in
>   that account using a fake but
>   descriptive website URL (e.g.
>   http://mymobileapp.mywebsite.com).
>   Once you create the profile, write
>   down or keep a copy of the web
>   property ID that is generated for the
>   newly-created profile. A Web property
>   ID is also known as the UA number of
>   your tracking code and looks like
>   UA-xxxxx-yy, where the x's and y's
>   indicate the unique numbers for your
>   profile. You must indicate the web
>   property ID you'd like to use when
>   instantiating the tracking object. See
>   Web Property for more information.

Appears to me you simply setup that "fake website"  such as http://myapp1.yourwebsite.com  and then you'll get a new UA- number which you plug into the code within myapp1.

App2 will have a different UA- number you use.

Comment: I stand corrected... there can be multiple account numbers per google account, but only 1 per profile. You were correct, but @jamie was able to clarify more specifically.